# Where will get the tooltip of coulmn header menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a grid in which column menuDisabled option is true. `menuDisabled : true`.

In menuDisabled I am getting `ascending` and `descending` options. I want to change the tooltip of ascending and descending. But I am not sure from where to change this.

Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: add an example link or code so we can help you

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya Hope you understood the question. Yes I will add example shortly

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya Updated.

Comment: $('#yourElementId').prop('title', 'your new title'); //try this using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could  try changing the `sortAscText` and `sortDescText` in `Ext.grid.GridView`

You can try configuring you grid with:

```
{
  ...
   viewConfig:{
      sortAscText: "MY SORT ASC TEXT"
      sortDescText: "MY SORT DESC TEXT"
  }
  ...
}
```

or you could just try setting it globally

```
Ext.grid.GridView.sortAscText = "MY SORT ASC TEXT"
Ext.grid.GridView.sortDescText = "MY SORT DESC TEXT"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this will change the text on ascending and descending. I want to change tool tip.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using? I tried to create this scenario in Sencha Fiddle, but I can't get the tooltip to show. I was using ExtJS 3.4